# Не запускается база данных Oracle. Файл SYSAUX01.DBF 0 байт

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

Имеется база данных Oracle 18c XE установленная в вирталку с Windows 7
Устанавливал сам по гайдам очень давно - в настройке базы не разбираюсь, пользуюсь только для APEX приложений

База стартует всегда сама при запуске винды.
В последний раз когда подключался к базе вышла ошибка ORA-01578: разрушен блок данных
После этого перезагрузил винду в виртуалке и запустилась проверка диска и исправление ошибок от самой винды (скрины прикрепил)

После загрузки винды база стартует, но ругается на файл C:\Oracle\oradata\XE\SYSAUX01.DBF
Он весит 0 байт
Подключиться можно только как sys as sysdba

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам SSD диск рабочий и относительно новый (84 дня работы)